# Docker-compose not mount the locale volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I thinks I have an error on my docker compose file.

When I launch "docker-compose up" I get an error  "web_1 | You have to be inside an ember-cli project in order to use the serve command." (i thnik the volume is not mounted.

I'm on ubuntu.

My docker-compose file in ./ :

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    links:
      - db
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

My dockerfile in ./ folder :

```
FROM ruby:2.2.0
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev
# for a JS runtime
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp
ADD Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
ADD . /myapp
```

My folder is located at : /data/Paul/sites/perso/codeflager/app-api

Comment: You have duplicate and conflicting `ADD` and `VOLUME`. Only need one of them. Probably remove `volumes` since your `npm install` depends on the `ADD`

Comment: Not working. I've also tried with the ember-cil image.

Comment: `ENV APP_HOME ./app-web` should be `ENV APP_HOME /app-web`

Comment: Not working, I've updated my issue

Comment: You have `volumes: app-api:/myapp`  in your `docker-compose.yml`.  Where is this `app-api` directory?  Is it a *subdirectory* of the directory containing the `docker-compose.yml` file?  Is it a named docker volume?

Comment: I have '.:/myapp' All is in /data/Paul/sites/perso/codeflager/app-api

Comment: Fixed, I'v just updated my docker version.